# Define a variable in Case statement at where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have created a SQL query that will run on a daily basis which will generate results based on the Days. For that, I have defined a variable in the where clause case statement to get the current day. Now when I run the query it shown an error stating Incorrect syntax near '='.

```
CASE 
when datename(dw,getdate()) = 'Monday' then PriceH_strMonday = '`Y'
when datename(dw,getdate()) = 'Tuesday' then PriceH_strTuesday = 'Y'
when datename(dw,getdate()) = 'Wednesday' then 'PriceH_strWednesday = 'Y'
when datename(dw,getdate()) = 'Thursday' then 'PriceH_strThursday = 'Y'
when datename(dw,getdate()) = 'Friday' then 'PriceH_strFriday = 'Y'
when datename(dw,getdate()) = 'Saturday' then 'PriceH_strSaturday = 'Y'
when datename(dw,getdate()) = 'Sunday' then 'PriceH_strSunday = 'Y'
end
```

If the case statement runs on Monday, then the statement will set 'Y' on PriceH_strMonday, and then it will generate data fall under Monday items.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Is this in a SELECT or in an UPDATE?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, it only has `CASE` **expressions** which return a scalar value, not a boolean result. I assuming this is in your `WHERE`, you should be using `AND` and `OR` logic.

Comment: 'Monday' then PriceH_strMonday = '`Y'  can you see anything wrong here?

Comment: @jarlh it's select only

Comment: @kelvin, I need to get the Day in order to meet my condition. If I set Static value like Monday, Tuesday then how come I compared the PriceH_strMonday = 'Y' or PriceH_strTuesday = 'N' etc

Comment: @Larnu, The Column PriceH_strMonday = Y and the PriceH_strTuesday = 'N' and PriceH_strWednesday = 'Y' means how come the query will produce proper results. I couldn't Use AND or OR operators. ALso the column values 'Y' and 'N' is dynamic values based on Day's.

Comment: *"ALso the column values 'Y' and 'N' is dynamic values based on Day's."* not according to the SQL you have shown us. They're all `Y`.

Comment: add queries to replicate your actual table also add expected result in question,

Comment: Is the case in the SELECT list, or in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, SQL Server doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements. I *assume* that the above is in the `WHERE`, in which case you shouldn't be trying to use a `CASE` **expression** either; just use `AND` and `OR` logic:

```sql
WHERE (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 'Monday' AND PriceH_strMonday = 'Y')
   OR (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 'Tuesday' AND PriceH_strTuesday = 'Y')
   OR (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 'Wednesday' AND PriceH_strWednesday = 'Y')
   OR (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 'Thursday' AND PriceH_strThursday = 'Y')
   OR (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 'Friday' AND PriceH_strFriday = 'Y')
   OR (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 'Saturday' AND PriceH_strSaturday = 'Y')
   OR (DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' AND PriceH_strSunday = 'Y')
```